# icingaweb2 not reachable

Tags: server, apache2, monitoring

the icingaweb2 is not reachable, although it is running on the server with the apache and icinga2. I already have all the prerequisites, that are documented on the [official site](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-2/latest/doc/02-installation/02-Ubuntu/) set up. However, when accessing the icingaweb2 site on apache (https://hostname/icingaweb2/setup) I get a **404 server error**

the link (https://hostname/) works and shows the **default site of apache**

**update:**

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

apache virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html


                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key





                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>


        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A few questions: (0) which version of Ubuntu are you running? (1) what is the content of your Apache virtual host configuration file? (2) have you restarted Apache since making changes to the settings?

Comment: @matigo good questions. I have added the first two points to the topic. Yes I have restarted it often